# Frequency of elements of vector x, as occuring in vector y

Tags: r, frequency

I have a vector x and want to get the frequency of occurences of elements of vector x in vector y.
in the end I need a dataframe with the first column showing the elements of x and the second column showing the frequency of these as they occur in vector y:

```
element_x frequency_in_y
hello            2
my               1
world            0
```

d

I have tried something clumsy as that but that doesn't do the trick.

`freq_x <- as_tibble(x) %>% mutate(Freq=str_count(x,  y))`

Update:

```
x <- c("hello", "my", "world")
y <- c("hello there", "this is my life", "hello", "bla")
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data  by using `dput()` ?

Comment: Hi, I added x and y...thx

Comment: `table(y)[x]` will give you a table of frequency of all existing elements, the rest will be <NA> columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option with `base R`,

```
out <- sapply(seq(x), function(i) sum(grepl(x[i],y)))

data.frame(element_x=x, frequency_in_y=out)
```

gives,

```
  element_x frequency_in_y
1     hello              2
2        my              1
3     world              0
```

**EDIT:**

For getting more than one occurances of a word you can run,

```
x <- c("hello", "my", "world")
y <- c("hello there", "this is my my life", "hello", "bla") # 2 my including now.


library(tidyverse)
out <- colSums(sapply(x, function(i) str_count(y, i)))
data.frame(element_x=x, frequency_in_y=out)

      element_x frequency_in_y
hello     hello              2
my           my              2
world     world              0
```

Comment: I think `sapply(x, function(i) sum(grepl(i,y)))` is simpler.

Comment: @Shree It gave a different output in my R session.

Comment: It works fine for me (as it should). Maybe try again in a fresh session.

Comment: thx...it does work indeed. However, working with grepl with either give you TRUE or FALSE for each element of y. Meaning, if and element of x occurs twice in an element of y this would not be taken into consideration, right?